# What language is this code?

Tags: programming-languages

I wonder what kind of language this code is (if it is even a language).

This was taken out of a machine which prints text on products using lasers, so it's probably some machine code or something: (i got it delivered in a *.lst file)

```
{
    PLACE  {
        BOX
    }    
    1816 1787 0 3696 0
}
{
    PLACE  {
        BOX
    }
    1816 1787 0 1760 0
} 
{
    PLACE  {
        BOX
    }
    1816 1787 0 -153 0
}
{
    PLACE  {
        BOX
    }
    1816 1787 0 -2142 0
}
{
    PLACE  {
        BOX
    }
    1816 1787 0 -4091 0
}
{
    INFO  Composition Producten1
}
{
    Script  {
        Producten
    }
}
{
    INFO  Producte1
}
{
    Graphic  {
    }
    -9508 0 7377 -5000 0 0
}
{
    Graphic  {
    }   
    -9590 984 6557 5000 0 0
}
{
    Graphic  {
    }
    -9426 -8852 -4153 0 0 0
}
{
    Graphic  {
    }   
    -9590 -8962 -5628 0 0 0
}
{
    Circle_TEXT  {
        1409
    }   
    542 1192 4552 1279 0 6240 1 DatroFont1 9999 9999
}
{
    TEXT  {
        43
    }    
    17951 2350 5137 5000 5246 5246  DatroFont1 0
} 
{
    TEXT  {
    }   
    -8115 -2787 6407 0 -1967 0 DatroFont1 0
}
{
    Circle_TEXT  {
        500001
    }   
    487 1192 3842 1279 0 6627 0 DatroFont1
}
{
    INFO  Producte2
}
{
    Graphic  {
    }  
    -9426 -929 3044 0 0 0
} 
{
    Graphic  {
    }   
    -9590 -8251 6066 0 0 0
} 
{
    Graphic  {
    }   
    -9590 -7322 -4153 0 0 0
} 
{
    Graphic  {
    }   
    -9754 -7486 -5683 0 0 0
} 
{
    Circle_TEXT  {
        1409
    }   
    542 1192 4552 1279 0 2835 1 DatroFont1 9999 9999
} 
{
    TEXT  {
    }   
    -8033 -874 3002 0 0 0 DatroFont1 0
} 
{
    TEXT  {
    }   
    -8115 820 3002 0 -1967 0 DatroFont1 0
} 
{
    Circle_TEXT  {
        500002
    }   
    487 1192 3842 1279 0 3222 0 DatroFont1
} 
{
    INFO  Producte3
} 
{
    Graphic  {
    }   
    -9426 -929 -415 0 0 0
} 
{
    Graphic  {
    }   
    -9508 -7268 6066 0 0 0
} 
{
    Graphic  {
    }   
    -9426 -6503 -4208 0 0 0
} 
{
    Graphic  {
    }   
    -9672 -6612 -5738 0 0 0
} 
{
    Circle_TEXT  {
        1409
    }   
    542 1192 4552 1279 0 -570 1 DatroFont1 9999 9999
} 
{
    TEXT  {
    }   
    -8033 -874 -403 0 0 0 DatroFont1 0
} 
{
    TEXT  {
    }   
    -8115 820 -403 0 -1967 0 DatroFont1 0
} 
{
    Circle_TEXT  {
        500003
    }   
    487 1192 3842 1279 0 -183 0 DatroFont1
} 
{
    INFO  Producte4
} 
{
    Graphic  {
    }   
    -9426 -929 -3874 0 0 0
} 
{
    Graphic  {
    }   
    -8934 2842 6066 0 0 0
} 
{
    Graphic  {
    }   
    -8934 2896 -4098 0 0 0
} 
{
    Graphic  {
    }   
    -8934 2842 -5847 0 0 0
} 
{
    Circle_TEXT  {
        1409
    }   
    542 1192 4552 1279 0 -3975 1 DatroFont1 9999 9999
} 
{
    TEXT  {
    }   
    -8033 -874 -3808 0 0 0 DatroFont1 0
} 
{
    TEXT  {
    }   
    -8115 820 -3808 0 -1967 0 DatroFont1 0
}
{
    Circle_TEXT  {
        500004
    }   
    487 1192 3842 1279 0 -3588 0 DatroFont1
} 
{
    INFO  Producte5
} 
{
    Graphic  {
    }   
    -9426 -929 -7333 0 0 0
} 
{
    Graphic  {
    }   
    -8934 6175 6066 0 0 0
} 
{
    Graphic  {
    }   
    -8934 6284 -4044 0 0 0
}
{
    Graphic  {
    }   
    -8934 6284 -6175 0 0 0
} 
{
    Circle_TEXT  {
        1409
    }   
    542 1192 4552 1279 0 -7380 1 DatroFont1 9999 9999
} 
{
    TEXT  {
    }   
    -8033 -874 -7213 0 0 0 DatroFont1 0
}
{
    TEXT  {
    }   
    -8115 820 -7213 0 -1967 0 DatroFont1 0
} 
{
    Circle_TEXT  {
        500005
    }   
    487 1192 3842 1279 0 -6993 0 DatroFont1
} 
RESTART {
    CharacterDistanceOffset  183
} 
{
    Parameter  {
        Producttest
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Interesting question (and +1 to it), but for someone to come up with a good answer might need a bit more context: what kind of machine is it (e.g. manufacturer, model name)? how old is the machine?

Comment: As i don't have access to the machine i can't give you any info about it. This is all i got unfortunately.. edit: I think it is running linux, not sure tho

Comment: Is this a joke? How do we know it's some sort of code rather than a spreadsheet.

Comment: I'd say it's just a *script* which is *interpreted* by a program (running in the machine's control unit). So I doubt it's a real PL. To me, it looks like a quite typical DSL written in [Tcl](http://www.tcl.tk) but don't get attached to this idea.

Comment: Looks like a printer or device control language. Could be for printer, plotter, NC, just about anything that needs to be controlled.

Answer (score 1):

It is very likely to be Postscript (based on the use of the `{` and `}` )